# perl run two system commands error

Tags: perl, unix, command, system

So in my script I need to make to calls to unix, and I do it via the system command like so:

```
system "bash -i -c 'addmothernode'";

...

perl code ...

...

system "bash -i -c 'addnode -ip=$_'";
```

However, whenever I run both of these commands in the same script, for some reason my process is stopped like this:

```
[1]+  Stopped                 perl boot.pl
```

And the script can only be finished when I run `fg %1`. When I only have one of these system calls in, the perl script finishes successfully. But I need both commands because they depend on each other. Anyone have any ideas about what's going on? Thanks!

UPDATE:

A lot of answers below are saying I don't need to use `bash -i` to run a system command, and I know typically this is true but I need to use aliases that I have created and if I do not use this the aliases won't be recognized. So I do need `bash -i`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is unrelated to perl. You can easily reproduce the situation if you start two bashes in the interactive mode (`-i`) one after another:

```
$ cat 1.sh 
bash -i -c 'sleep 1'
bash -i -c 'sleep 1'

$ bash 1.sh

[1]+  Stopped                 bash 1.sh
```

Of course it would be better to run bash in the non-interactive mode (without `-i`) or run the program directly, without bash, but if you need for some reason `bash -i` you can protect its run with `setsid`:

```
$ cat 1.sh
setsid bash -i -c 'sleep 1'
setsid bash -i -c 'sleep 1'
echo done

$ bash 1.sh
done
```

Comment: Great!! Thank you! I need the `bash -i` to run my aliases in the command. This is exactly what I needed :)

Comment: I'm glad to help you! Another solution for you: `bash -c '. ~/.bashrc ; echo done'`. Instead of `echo done` must be your command.

Answer (score 2):

The `bash -i` means run an interactive shell; so you have two shells both reading from the terminal.

Try removing the `-i` options.

Answer (score 2):

```
system "addmothernode";
```

should work.

---

To execute a command, bash is not needed. The Perl `system` function is like the system C function, it calls by default `sh`.

[man system](http://cims.nyu.edu/cgi-systems/man.cgi?section=3C&topic=system)

[exec](http://cims.nyu.edu/cgi-systems/man.cgi?section=2&topic=exec)

The standard to which the caller conforms determines which shell is used. See [standards(5)](http://cims.nyu.edu/cgi-systems/man.cgi?section=5&topic=standards).

```
Standard                                      Shell Used
______________________________________________________________
1989 ANSI  C,  1990  ISO  C,  1999  ISO  C,   /usr/xpg4/bin/sh
POSIX.1  (1990-2001),  SUS,  SUSv2,  SUSv3,
XPG4
POSIX.1 (1988), SVID3,  XPG3,  no  standard   /usr/bin/sh
specified
```